# Error #1009 with Buttons (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

Throughout my little game I get typeerror #1009 with all of my buttons.

An example of one of my buttons is this:

```
creditsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, creditsButtonClick);
function creditsButtonClick(event:MouseEvent) {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, creditsButtonClick);
    gotoAndPlay(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not clear what part of code throws that error. You should debug it and check what is null. Second, you remove the event listener incorrectly. You are adding it to creditsButton but removing it from another object. The code should be

```
creditsButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, creditsButtonClick);
```

Comment: I fixed it, I forgot to change a button that was faulting my hole code, I appreciate your answer anyway.